# keyboard change language event

Tags: react-native

in a multi-language(for now Persian and English) application, Customers can type either Persian(RTL) or English(LTR).

When they tap on a TextInput, I want to set its direction RTL or LTR by keyboard's selected language.

When the language is Persian, TextInput should be RTL and vice versa.
When the customer types  the first character, I can choose direction depending on that character.
I saw such ability in many apps like telegram and I told my self what if i can have it in mine.
A full checking source code is wonderful but I just want a keyboard handler for the change language event,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you maybe post the relevant code and tell us where exactly your got stuck?

Comment: my code now just change Persian and Arabic numbers to English in 'onChangeText' listener and I did not implement RTL aware layout yet,  in the simplest explanation, I want an event listener on the keyboard's language changing that gives me at least a flag about selected language in react native

Comment: I got that keyboard have a minor change of frame size on changing language and react native have a 'keyboardWillChangeFrame' listener and this can get the job done, but we don't know the language that selected yet